# Redirect from index.html.erb to a controller method with params

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameter-passing, embedded-ruby

I have a partial _filter.html.erb which uses simple-form. The first line is:

```
<%= simple_form_for :filter, url: index_panel_path, :method => "get", :html => { :id => "search_by_id"} do |f| %>
```

So, on click filter button, it calls index_panel_path with params[:filter].
The index.html.erb has this line:

```
<li><a href=<%= grocery_panel_path %> >Grocery Panel</a></li>
```

This calls the grocery_panel method in the controller. The problem is that I am getting the params[:filter] in index.html, but in the grocery method  the params[:filter] is nil. Any idea how can I send the params there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it manually like:-

```
<li><a href=<%= grocery_panel_path(:filter => "some_value") %> >Grocery Panel</a></li>
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot.